# SU setgid: PERMISSION DENIED, SUDO: PERM_ROOT 0, -1, 1 PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: command-line, permissions, ssh, sudo, root

Hi I have a problem that I cannot solve.

I cannot log into root, `su`, or `sudo`.

Everything works fine via ssh so I tried on ssh via putty:

- Set root password: `sudo passwd`
- Add user to sudo/admin group : `sudo useradd myuser`
- Run `sudo visudo` and add `myuser` in `sudoers`
- ...

But when I use the normal Ubuntu terminal on the Ubuntu desktop it gives this error:

```
sudo: PERM_ROOT (0, -1, -1) PERMISSION DENIED
```

when I try to get su access:

```
su: Password:
setgid: PERMISSION DENIED.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Askubuntu. Please provide as much details as you can about the things you have done so that we can get the total picture of the issue.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and upload your `/etc/sudoers` file to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use

```
sudo -i
```

to log in as root on a local machine's terminal.